# What does a -1 mean in the shape of a tensor input?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I've got a TensorFlowJS model that has an input that looks like this:

```
{"name":"dense_3_input","shape":[-1,25],"dtype":"float32"}
```

What does the -1 mean?

The way the model is constructed is using `Dense(1, input_dim=25, activation="sigmoid")` so I don't know where the -1 is coming from or how to properly create the tensor that it's looking for.

If I pass a tensor of

```
tf.tensor([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

I get this error.

```
Error: The shape of dict['dense_3_input'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,25], but was [25]
```

The model works correctly in python when passed the above input of 25 0/1's. Did the conversion to a TensorFlowJS model not work correctly? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding another surrounding [] around your list.  -1 means a variable/undetermined number.

Comment: @mark-h wow that was it! Thank you! I was assuming that I needed to map my data to an array of tensors instead of creating a single tensor with my array of data. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-1 in a dimension of a tensor means that that dimension's size will be computed as regard the other dimensions. The tensor shape should be a multiple of the product of the size of the other dimensions for it to work

```
tensor size: 25, shape [-1, 25] => [1, 25]

                 shape [-1, 5] => [5, 5]

                 shape [-1, 3] => will not work
```

It is useful when we don't know the size of the tensor but know that it will be a multiple of some values.

In the example of the question, the initial tensor can be reshaped:

- `tf.tensor([0, 1...]).reshape([-1, 25])` or
- it can be constructed directly as a 2d tensor `tf.tensor([[0, 1...]])`

Comment: Thank you! I got similar problem, but mine is a little different, `a_init(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),dtype='float32')`, so what `input_shape[-1]` here means please?

Answer (score 0):

-1 means an undetermined number, as in it can be whatever you want.

If you are passing in a single tensor of shape [25], you need to add surrounding brackets, so the shape becomes [1,25], which would be valid.

Try:

```
tf.tensor([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Are you sure? Isn't `null` the shape placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in @mark-h's comment, the issue is that I was passing a single array of values to the tensor with `tf.tensor([0, 1...])`. The [-1, 25] is saying that there is an undetermined number of arrays containing 25 values that the input is expecting.

Changing my tensor to `tf.tensor([[0, 1...]])` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

provide the input as [-1,25] which means that first unit (-1) can be ANY number so it would accept [1,25] or [5,25], etc. The first dimension can be anything in the 2 dimensional number.